# Here API: Avoid borders crossing

Tags: here-api

is there any way to not cross countries borders with transit? I mean I want to travel from one EU country to another, but Here api routes through not EU member country and it's a bad route. For example, from Vilnius (Lithuania) to Gdansk (Polland) routes via Kaliningrad (Russia) or from Vilnius (Lithuania) to Bialystok (Polland) via Belorussia.

Comment: Please provide your exact request and response inorder to help us serve you better.

Comment: Kaunas-Gdansk goes via Kaliningrad, what is absolutely uncommon: https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&waypoint0=geo!54.898521,23.903597&waypoint1=geo!54.352025,18.646638&tollVehicleType=3&mode=fastest;truck;dirtRoad:-2&cost_optimize=0&vehicleWeight=40.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=11.5t&height=4.0m&detail=1&rollup=country&currency=EUR&commercial=1&routeAttributes=routeId,shape&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerNumberAxles=3&trailerHeight=4.0

Comment: Second Vilnius-Bialystok goes via Belorussia, what is absolutely uncommon: https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&waypoint0=geo!54.687156,25.279651&waypoint1=geo!53.132489,23.16884&tollVehicleType=3&mode=fastest;truck;dirtRoad:-2&cost_optimize=0&vehicleWeight=40.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=11.5t&height=4.0m&detail=1&rollup=country&currency=EUR&commercial=1&routeAttributes=routeId,shape&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerNumberAxles=3&trailerHeight=4.0

Comment: Both requests routes via border crossings. Both requests have mode=fastest, what makes response bad. As user, I have to make route between first point and some kind of medium point, then mid-point to second point. You don't have soke kind of border crossing time weight or time penalty while calculating route via border. As I mentioned, path must be on EU countries, but not on Russia or Belorussia - Vilnius (Lithuania) - Bialystok (Polland) not via Belorussia and Kaunas (Lithuania)-Gdansk (Poland) not via Kaliningrad (Russia).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by explicitly stating in the routing api to avoid a country or an area.

1. avoidareas parameter - you can provide a set of geo cordinates or links to avoid while calculating the route.

   https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&avoidareas=54.855357,19.989972;54.294932,22.802473&cost_optimize=0&detail=1&tollvehicletype=3&vehicleweight=40.0t&height=4.0&jsonattributes=41&language=en-us&limitedweight=40.0&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=fastest;truck;dirtRoad:-2&routeattributes=sh,gr&waypoint0=geo!54.898521,23.903597&waypoint1=geo!54.352025,18.646638&weightperaxle=11.5
2. excludecountries parameter - You can provide the list of countries to avoid while calculating the route

   https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code={YOUR-APP-CODE}&app_id={YOUR-APP-ID}&excludecountries=RUS&cost_optimize=0&detail=1&tollvehicletype=3&vehicleweight=40.0t&height=4.0&jsonattributes=41&language=en-us&limitedweight=40.0&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=fastest;truck;dirtRoad:-2&routeattributes=sh,gr&waypoint0=geo!54.898521,23.903597&waypoint1=geo!54.352025,18.646638&weightperaxle=11.5

Read more about these in our developer site. Happy Coding!